# Running an if statement against a variable set as None.

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter, nonetype

Might just be too new this to accurately find what I am looking. I have a variable I preset to None globally to update the value of `var1` from `func1`. If that first function was not ran to update `Var1` from None, is there a method to do an if statement on the `None` variable, to do some action if it is confirmed it is still set to None.  I have tried ==, != "1", and many other familiars, but not finding a way through. Here is an example with tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tkinter
from tkinter import Frame
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()

class Stupid_app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=2)

        Var1 = None

        def func1():
            global Var1
            Var1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()  # Open file to get path
            label.config(text=Var1)   # Updates the label
            print(Var1)
            return Var1

        def func2():
            global Var1
            if Var1 is not None:
                print("var is not none")
            else:
                quit()


        Button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Get Path", command=func1)
        Button1.pack()

        label = tkinter.Label(root, text="^^Select File ^^")
        label.pack()

        Button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Run a Fuction", command=func2)
        Button2.pack()

app = Stupid_app(root)
root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Rather setting globals, presetting variable as a string, it seems to always return **NameError: name 'var1' is not defined** on line 22 that contains the if statement **if var1 is "":**. Ive also tried setting the variable inside and outside the function with `"a"`, or simliar. 
I have read on several location this is not possible, nor is it possible to use None in this manner, but I do not see any alternatives. Any assistance is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between an undefined variable and a defined variable set to `None`. An undefined variable doesn't have a value because it doesn't exist yet.

The `Var1` in your example code is local to `__init__`, not a global. You could add another global statement in `__init__` to make it global.

You could instead move the `Var1 = None` to the toplevel of your script (outside the class definition) to define a global `Var1`. Then it will be `None` until it gets set to something else.

Since your functions are nested inside `__init__` you don't have to use globals at all. You could use `nonlocal` instead of `global` to refer to a containing function's local. This is only required in `func1` because it is assigning to `Var1`. (You can read nonlocals and globals without declaring them as such.)

Comment: The `Var1 = None` is at line 11. Typo on my last edit before post, original case sensitivity was accurate. Setting Global within both functions (as identified previously, produces same result.  Function 2 only works correctly if Function 1 has been run, but the if I am trying to catch is in the event function 2 is started before Function 1, where Var1  is still set to None. Can the if statement run checking if the `Var1` is still set to `None` or not. Running multiple terations of this `is not None`, `!= "a"1`, `== None`, and a few others always returns `NameError: name 'Var1' is not defined`